# String index out of range: -1

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

```
//filename 1.xml

<category 
hello world
</category>
//when iam trying to parse this file using the following code it throws String index out of range: -1
 output: startPos: -1
         endPosi: -1

 String dataLine = nextLine.trim();
 int startPos = dataLine.indexOf(startToken);
 logger.debug("startPos: " + startPos);
 int endPosi = dataLine.lastIndexOf(endToken);
 logger.debug("endPosi: " + endPosi);

// 2.xml it parses this file which contains the following line

<category hello world </category>
```

// the only difference between those two files are content of the first file is in three lines and the content of second file is in one single line.

Comment: what is the ``startToken``?  Also, your XML is invalid.  It should read ``<category>`` (note the '>')

Comment: String startToken = "<" + "category"+ " ";

Comment: I bet that first line is `<categoryEOL`. There's no literal whitespace here - just the End Of Line symbol (CR/LF, choose your pick). That's why in that case `indexOf` finds nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your input file to:

```
<category>
    hello world
</category>
```

and then your start token to:

```
String startToken = "<category>";
```

One problem you have is that `<category` is invalid XML.  The `.trim()` is stripping the trailing space on the first line of the first file.  Short answer:  Fix you XML.

Comment: the file looks something like this so i need to extract the information from start to end tag of category                                                              <category link="http://images/113264.gif" id="1"><names><name lang="de">Top Downloads</name><name lang="ww">Tops</name></names></category>

Comment: You really don't want to be writing your own XML parser.  Its a very complicated business.  Have a look at [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) on how to use an existing XML parser to read your XML.

Answer (score 0):

The method [`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) removes the trailing white space. Now [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't find "`<category`" (with a trailing space) and returns `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int startPos = dataLine.indexOf(startToken);
```

I think there is no startToken in your dataLine string so its returning -1;

[String#indexOf("str")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)

> if the string argument occurs as a substring within this object, then
>   the index of the first character of the first such substring is
>   returned; if it does not occur as a substring, -1 is returned.